# Lightning-datatable: Inline editing with checkbox doesn't work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, inline-editing

I have a lightning datatable that works, I can save the changes that I did, with no problem, using oncellchange. The only problem that I having is use checkbox option with inline editing. When you select more than one line and goes edit a field, it shows the option to update the selected lines with the same information, like in the image, the problem is, this doesn't triggers oncellchange or onsave, so, in the screen view is updated but I'm not able to save it in a variable. How can I get this action and the data after the change?

[image]